# “white-space: nowrap;” destroys flexbox layout: Why?

Tags: css, flexbox

This is my code:

```css
* {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: blue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
}

#one {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#two,
#four {
  width: 45px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#three {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#button,
#text {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

#text {
  width: 100%;
  /* overflow: auto;
 white-space: nowrap; */
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
    <div id="button">Button</div>
  </div>
  <div id="four">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add `white-space: nowrap;` for the text (`#text`), but it destroys the layout, the areas with the blue backgrounds get lost. I saw that adding `min-width: 0;` or `min-height: 0;` could help, but it doesn't work in this case.

Has somebody an idea to fix that? Would be very thankful. :)

For clarifying: The text from `#text` should stay in one line, that's all.

Comment: there is no white-space in your code. also define what you mean by *destroy*

Comment: did you try overflow:auto instead of min-width:0 ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! Hope my question is now clearer. "overflow: auto;" doesn't make a difference, unfortunately.

Comment: are you sure? https://jsfiddle.net/u8vrp0L4/1/

Comment: Okay, sorry. You are right! But I had to edit the question because the layout I'm working with is a bit different.

Comment: add min-width:0 to three and overflow auto to text inside it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is happening?**

The divs `two`, `three` and `four` are had the `flex` property set to its default values:

```
div {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-base: auto
}
```

Which means that for each div should: calculate the "best" width (flex-base: auto), if there is enough space for the three divs there is no need to grow to fill it (flex-grow: 0), if there isn't enough space shrink them proportionally (flex-shrink: 1).

When you put `white-space: nowrap;` in the `three` div, there is not enough space (since it "best" width will be as much as is needed to hold the single long line of text.

**Solution:**

Add `flex-shrink: 0` to the blue divs, and `flex-grow: 1` and `overflow: auto` to the central div. This way, the blue divs will always have 45px width, and the central one will always fill the remaining space.

**UPDATE**

Since you now have a new  div and button inside div `three`, there is a few additional changes: We'll make div `three` also a flex container, and set flex-grow and flex-shrink to appropriate values for the inner text and button.

```css
* {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: blue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

div {
  height: 100px; /* You'll probably want a lower height */
}

#one {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#two,
#four {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* no shrink */
  width: 45px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#three {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1; /* fill all available space */
  width: 0px; /* will grow from 0px to fill all space*/
}

#text {
  flex-grow: 1; /* fill all available space */
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap; /* moved from "#three" */
  overflow: auto; /* moved from "#three" */
}

#button {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* no shrink */
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
    <div id="button">Button</div>
  </div>
  <div id="four">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, this looks very good. But I had to update my question. And if I just do it like you did it here, then it doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `flex-basis` property of `div#three`, `div#two`, and `div#four` to something like `33.3%`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis

You're also setting the height of all `div`s to `100vh`, and when the overflow occurs on your inner block elements, it doesn't know where to stop unless you truncate the text: https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/

```css
* {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: blue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#one {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#two,
#four {
  flex-basis: 33%;
  width: 45px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#three {
  width: 100%;
  flex-basis: 33%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
  <div id="four">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And you can probably get the other divs (`two` and `four`) to be the exact same width as `div#three` by entering some content. Check out Bootstrap. It does all of that for you.

Comment: You're essentially trying to do this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ Just download Bootstrap and use the CSS for `row` and `col`.

Comment: But in in the blue areas should be text later, and the with of the blue boxes should fit exactly to the text with ... I think that doesn't help me. But thanks!

Comment: @Anna_B That's because you're overflowing out of the inner block element that is set to `100vh`. Check the updated answer — I included a section about truncating text within flexbox. You're question isn't very clear as to what you mean by "destroying" the blue areas. https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/

Comment: @Anna_B Maybe this is what you mean? Check the updated snippet.

Comment: What @Temani Afif did (https://jsfiddle.net/u8vrp0L4/1/) is nearly what I need. But it doesn't work for my updated question ...

Comment: @Anna_B I still don't understand the problem well enough. The flexbox itself is not getting "destroyed". That's how flexbox is supposed to behave. So, maybe you could tell me more about these blue areas? The goal is unclear.

Comment: If you take the code from my question: The text in the #text area should stay in one line. It should be a marquee ticker later.

Comment: @Anna_B Check the updated answer. If you don't want the blue sections to go the height of the viewport, then remove `height: 100vh;` from your `div`s

Comment: @Anna_B If you're looking to add ellipsis to the marquee, then use `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Comment: Hmh. I think it works in general, but not for my updated question.

Comment: Be sure to react to the answer if this helps you.

Comment: @Anna_B Sorry, maybe you could post an illustration of what it is that you are trying to achieve? I still don't understand the goal.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), setting `white-space: nowrap` "suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within the source." This means that all of your line breaks will be gone for that element and it will go on horizontally as long as there is text.

But to keep everything within the viewport and keep the blue bars around the text, you should first wrap your Lorem Ipsum text in a `p` tag or other text element, and then change your CSS to something like this:

```css
:root {
    --bar_width: 45px;
}

* {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: blue;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  div {
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  #one {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100vw;
    
  }
  
  #two,
  #four {
    width: var(--bar_width);
    background-color: blue;

  }
  
  #three p {

    max-width: calc(95vw - (2 * var(--bar_width)));
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="one">
        <div id="two">
        </div>
        <div id="three">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="four">
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This adds an `overflow` property set to `scroll` so that the text can be reached without it streching out the viewport. I also set the max width the element can take up so that CSS knows when to start cutting off the text. I also added `flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between;` to your `#one` selector so that the elements space out horizontally.

You can now change the `max-width` property set in the `#three p` selector to any value you want and the text (with scroll) will be centered between the blue bars.